# SharePoint designer 2010 change in workflow not visible

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I try to update an existing workflow in SharePoint 2010 that is created with SharePoint Designer 2010 the workflow never gets updated until a recycle of the SharePoint server.

It's a simple workflow that logs a message to the workflow history. When I change the text of the message this new message doesn't get visible when I start a new instance of the workflow.

Only after 24 hours (after an automatic recycle of the SharePoint Server) the new message gets visible. Is there a specific timerjob that is causing that the latest update is visible?

What I've tried:

- Clearing the cache folder of SharePoint Designer
- Reinstall SharePoint designer

Comment: What I do for Workflows created in Visual studio is to remove the workflow from the list, disable the feature, retract the solution, re deploy, re enable and re create the workflow in the list, try to see/check if you can do something similar with Designer.

Comment: This is not a solution if you have many workflows to manage and you want to make a small change. In SharePoint 2007 it wasn't a problem to make a change on SharePoint designer workflows. Maybe something went wrong during the upgrade? Is it a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Found the solution:

My colleagues disabled all versioning on all libraries in the farm. Including the libraries where the workflows are stored. When versioning is disabled the latest version will not be visible in SharePoint inmediately only after an IISReset.

Thanks all!